# Formal way to express the number of lists of $k$ objects from $n$, having $i$ unique elements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Say that I have a matrix of the $n^k$ ordered lists of $k$ objects from a supply of $n$, with replacement (which I am not quite sure how it's called). Note that $k$ may be greater, equal, or less than $n$. Here is an example (in `R` language):

```
k <- 5 
n <- 3 

m <- expand.grid(data.frame(matrix(rep(c(1:n),k),ncol=k)))
```

Here is a sample from that matrix:

```
m[sample(nrow(m),10),]
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
9    3  3  1  1  1
168  3  2  1  1  3
166  1  2  1  1  3
233  2  3  2  3  3
11   2  1  2  1  1
60   3  2  1  3  1
20   2  1  3  1  1
64   1  1  2  3  1
49   1  2  3  2  1
54   3  3  3  2  1
```

Is there a formal way to express the number of results (i.e. rows) with $i$ unique occurrences (where $1 \le i \le n$), as a function of $k$, $n$ and $i$ ? (which is exactly what the following R command returns):

```
table(apply(m,1,function(x) length(unique(x)))) 

  1   2   3 
  3  90 150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you know that your "rows" are like a function from $[5]$ to $[3]$ where $[n]=\{1,2,\cdots , n\}$. You want to choose a set of $i$ elements from the set $[n]$ in such a way that every possible outcome appears, so in other words you want your configuration to be surjective in the $i$ elements you picked. 
So let $A_{k,i}$ denote the number of surjective functions from $[k]$ to $[i]$, by the product law you will have ${{n}\choose{i}}A_{k,i}$.
To know how to calculate the $A_{k,i}$ number it is $i!S_{k,i}$, where $S_{k,i}$ is the Stirling numbers of the second kind.